# Как добавить на сайт возможность создать аккаунт и войти в него

Tags: веб-программирование, flask

Недавно я начал изучать flask и сейчас создаю сайт. И я не очень понимаю как реализовать возможность создания аккаунта и входа в него. Можете объяснить новичку примерный алгоритм?

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы реализовать функционал учетных записей (аккаунтов) на сайте, с возможностью аутентификации/авторизации достаточно:
1) настроить использование СУБД для сайта (SQLAlchemy)
2) создать модель данных профиля пользователя
3) инициализировать модель в бд (Alembic)
4) подключить и настроить библиотеку для реализации аутентификации/авторизации (Flask-Login)